# Ruby JSON returns fine but crashes on Parse

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON returned from my an API I am working on. The response I am getting is

```
puts res.body
{"error"=>true, "message"=>"Login failed. Incorrect credentials"}
```

but if I try and and parse it with JSON it crashes.

```
   connection = Connection.new
   res = connection.post("login", {'email':'test@email.com', 'password': 'somepass'})
   puts JSON.parse(res.body)
   puts res.code
   puts res.body
```

also I have tried but it returns nothing

```
puts res["error"]
puts res[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your `res` hash object to a JSON object by calling: `res.to_json`. Then you will be able to call `JSON.parse` on that object, like this:

```
res = connection.post("login", { 'email': 'test@email.com', 'password': 'somepass' })
result = JSON.parse(res.to_json)
# => {"error"=>true, "message"=>"Login failed. Incorrect credentials"}
result['error']
# => true
result['message']
# => "Login failed. Incorrect credentials"
```

Comment: Thanks K M Rakibul Islam, can you tell me why i have .to_json inside of JSON.parse?

Comment: Because, you need to convert the hash to a json using `to_json` call in order to parse the json with `JSON.parse` method. Otherwise, your program will crash with this error message: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String`.

Comment: ahh so even using JSON.parse it still is a hash. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yeah it does, just waiting for the accept timer to allow me :)